# Combine two tables into one in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have two tables named `users` and `offers`

`users` table

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | username | role      |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | A        | client    |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 2  | B        | client    |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 3  | C        | candidate |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 4  | D        | candidate |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 5  | E        | candidate |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

`offers` table

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | client_id | candidate_id |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 1  | 1         | 3            |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 2  | 2         | 4            |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 3  | 1         | 5            |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 4  | 2         | 3            |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 5  | 2         | 5            |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

I want to create a query to combine `offers` table with `users` table, like

```
+----+-----------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+
| id | client_id | client_username | candidate_id | candidate_username |
+----+-----------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 1  | 1         | A               | 3            | C                  |
+----+-----------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 2  | 2         | B               | 4            | D                  |
+----+-----------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 3  | 1         | A               | 5            | E                  |
+----+-----------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 4  | 2         | B               | 3            | C                  |
+----+-----------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 5  | 2         | B               | 5            | E                  |
+----+-----------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

I have written 2 queries that are working separately, but I want to combine these into one table.

```
SELECT offers.candidate_id, users.username AS candidate_username
FROM offers INNER JOIN users ON offers.candidate_id = users.id;

SELECT offers.client_id, users.username AS client_username
FROM offers INNER JOIN users ON offers.client_id = users.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT offers.candidate_id, 
       a.username AS client_username,a1.username as candidate_username 
FROM offers left JOIN users a ON offers.client_id = a.id
left join users a1 ON offers.candidate_id = a1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Left Join` for this purpose like:

```
SELECT offers.candidate_id, 
       a.username AS client_username,a1.username AS candidate_username 
FROM offers left JOIN users a ON offers.client_id = a.id OR offers.candidate_id = a.id;
```